# How do I store an intermediate convolutional layer's result in tensorflow for later processing?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

The image below describes the output before the application of a max-pooling layer of a single intermediate filter layer of a CNN. 
I want to store the co-ordinates of the pixel with intensity 4(on the bottom right of the matrix on the LHS of the arrow) as it is in the matrix on the LHS of the arrow. That is the pixel at co-ordinate (4,4)(1 based indexing)in the right matrix is the one which is getting stored in the bottom right cell of the matrix on the RHS of the arrow, right. Now what I want to do is to store this co-ordinate value (4,4) along with the co-ordinates for the other pixels {(2,2) for pixel with intensity 6, (2, 4) for pixel with intensity 8 and (3, 1) for pixel with intensity 3} as a list for later processing. How do I do it in Tensorflow. [image: max pooling done with filter of size 2 x 2 and stride 2]

**Max pooling done with a filter of size 2 x 2 and stride of 2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax` ([link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/max_pool_with_argmax)). 
**Note：**

> The indices in argmax are flattened, so that a maximum value at
>   position [b, y, x, c] becomes flattened index ((b * height + y) *
>   width + x) * channels + c.

We need to do some processing to make it fit your coordinates.
An example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def max_pool_with_argmax(net,filter_h,filter_w,stride):
    output, mask = tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax( net,ksize=[1, filter_h, filter_w, 1],
                                            strides=[1, stride, stride, 1],padding='SAME')

    # If your ksize looks like [1, stride, stride, 1]
    loc_x = mask // net.shape[2]
    loc_y = mask % net.shape[2]
    loc = tf.concat([loc_x+1,loc_y+1],axis=-1) #count from 0 so add 1

    # If your ksize is all changing, use the following
    # c = tf.mod(mask,net.shape[3])
    # remain = tf.cast(tf.divide(tf.subtract(mask,c),net.shape[3]),tf.int64)
    # x = tf.mod(remain,net.shape[2])
    # remain = tf.cast(tf.divide(tf.subtract(remain,x),net.shape[2]),tf.int64)
    # y = tf.mod(remain,net.shape[1])
    # remain = tf.cast(tf.divide(tf.subtract(remain, y), net.shape[1]),tf.int64)
    # b = tf.mod(remain, net.shape[0])
    # loc = tf.concat([y+1,x+1], axis=-1)
    return output,loc

input = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(1, 6, 4, 1), dtype=np.float32)
output, mask = max_pool_with_argmax(input,2,2,2)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    input_value,output_value,mask_value = sess.run([input,output,mask])
    print(input_value[0,:,:,0])
    print(output_value[0,:,:,0])
    print(mask_value[0,:,:,:])

#print
[[0.20101677 0.09207255 0.32177696 0.34424785]
 [0.4116488  0.5965447  0.20575707 0.63288754]
 [0.3145412  0.16090539 0.59698933 0.709239  ]
 [0.00252096 0.18027237 0.11163216 0.40613824]
 [0.4027637  0.1995668  0.7462126  0.68812144]
 [0.8993007  0.55828506 0.5263306  0.09376772]]
[[0.5965447  0.63288754]
 [0.3145412  0.709239  ]
 [0.8993007  0.7462126 ]]
[[[2 2]
  [2 4]]

 [[3 1]
  [3 4]]

 [[6 1]
  [5 3]]]
```

You can see (2,2) for pixel with intensity 0.5965447, (2, 4) for pixel with intensity 0.63288754 and so on.

Comment: what if my ksize looks like [1,filter_h,filter_w,1]?

Comment: @AnubhavPandey You need to do is add parameters. I've changed it in the answer when your ksize looks like [1,filter_h,filter_w,1].

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the following max-pooling layer:

```
pool_layer= tf.nn.max_pool(conv_output,
                           ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                           strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                           padding='VALID')
```

you can use:

```
max_pos = tf.gradients([pool_layer], [conv_output])[0]
```